# Cos'è la "colla acustica" in questo brano?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *Il cielo di pietra*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> La corazza del rumore s'estendeva di là in poi sulla superficie del globo: la fascia che delimita la vostra vita extraterrestre, con le antenne inalberate sui tetti a trasformare in suono le onde che percorrono invisibili e inudibili lo spazio, coi transistor appiccicati agli orecchi per riempirli in ogni istante della *colla acustica* senza la quale non sapete se siete vivi o morti, coi jukebox che immagazzinano e rovesciano suoni, e l'ininterrotta sirena dell'ambulanza che raccoglie ora per ora i feriti della vostra carneficina ininterrotta.

Ho cercato il significato di "colla" in alcuni dizionari. Comunque non riesco a capire cosa significa "colla acustica" nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Tenete conto che il narratore di questo brano abita nell'interno del globo terrestre. Per questa ragione parla di "vita extraterrestre" per riferirsi alla nostra vita sulla superficie della Terra.

Comment: I _transistor_ sono le radioline a transistor, e la _colla acustica_ è la sostanza appiccicosa fatta di musica e notizie che ne esce.

Comment: Non voglio dire che sia off-topic, ma questa è a malapena comprensibile anche a un madrelingua, "colla acustica" è pura licenza poetica, e certamente non un sinonimo di "trasmissione radiofonica". Comunque @WalterTross potresti scriverlo come risposta? Credo sia esattamente come dici tu.

Comment: @kos: Capisco, grazie!

Comment: @WalterTross: Sono d'accordo con kos: potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: @Charo Comunque fammi precisare che non voleva essere rivolto a te il commento, un non madrelingua non è certo tenuto a saperlo e ovviamente non ha senso parlare di cose come "capirlo prima di postare la domanda". L'ho scritto giusto per precisare, e soprattutto col senno di poi.

Comment: Ti prego @kos, fallo tu – grazie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qui "colla acustica" è sicuramente una metafora (molto lontana) di "trasmissione radiofonica".

Comunque non è semplicissimo interpretare il collegamento con la colla. La mia migliore ipotesi è che citare la colla voglia essere un rimarco del fatto, successivamente precisato, che "senza quella non sapremmo se siamo vivi o morti".

"Colla" perché dipendevamo così strettamente da tali trasmissioni radiofoniche (quantomeno al tempo della stesura del racconto) da essere di fatto "appiccicati" ad esse come colla (o forse meglio espresso, risultavano talmente utili / interessanti da "appiccicarsi" a noi come colla).

Comment: @Charo Grazie per la correzione dell'accento, ma il punto e virgola e a capo è una costruzione corretta, sebbene discutibilmente bella e forse antiquata (comunque trovo che serva bene lo scopo di illustrare un ragionamento).

Comment: Scusa, @kos, ma il punto e virgola e a capo e poi una frase che comincia con la maiuscola? Questo non l'avevo mai visto.

Comment: @Charo Non è un argomento molto dibatutto (è piuttosto ristretta come tematica), l'unica prova a parziale supporto del fatto che sia corretto sia andare a capo che usare la maiuscola dopo un punto e virgola è questa risposta di Giorgio De Rienzo su corriere.it: http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/03-06-2008/punto_e_virgola-1076768.html?refresh_ce-cp. Non dice esplicitamente che è corretto farlo, ma dice che non è richiesto, lasciando intendere che sia opzionale. Comunque sono d'accordo che non sia bellissimo. Però mi sembra utile per far capire che si sta facendo un ragionamento.

Comment: kos, non ti capisco bene. Anche a me vedere quel a capo e quella maiuscola dopo il punto e virgola fa pensare subito a una svista (a maggior ragione visto che poi tra un punto e virgola e il successivo ci sono punti fermi): non ricordo niente di simile, se non forse qualche lungo elenco molto formale, forse di commi in una legge. E poi il “non richiesto” nella pagina che citi, per giunta rafforzato subito dopo da un “tanto meno”, sembra un modo per dire che che non va messo (una litote come “‘qui’ non vuole l'accento”: non significa che non lo desideri, ma se glielo mettiamo lo accetta).

Comment: @DaG Non so, sono sicuro di averlo visto in precedenza, comunque di nuovo, sono d'accordo che non sia bellissimo. Visto che siete già in due a pensarla così comunque non insisto oltre, li sostituisco con un punto.